# Is it normal when you get different coefficients everytime your run your LR model code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
#REGRESSION ANALYSIS
#splitting the dataset into x and y variables
firm1=pd.DataFrame(firm, columns=['Sales', 'Advert', 'Empl', 'Prod'])
print(firm1)
x = firm1.drop(['Sales'], axis=1)
y = firm1['Sales']
print(x)
print(y)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2)
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

#the LR model
M=linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
M.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred=M.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred)
print('Coeff: ', M.coef_)
for i in M.coef_:
    print('{:.4f}'.format(i))

print('Intercept: ','{:.4f}'.format(M.intercept_))
print('MSE: ','{:.4f}'.format(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
print('Coeffieicnt of determination (r2): ','{:.4f}'.format(r2_score(y_test, y_pred)))
print(firm1.sample())
```

This is my linear regression model. Every time I run the code, I get a different sent of coefficient for the x variables and the Intercept. I cannot have a constant equation. Is that normal?

> Coeff:  [454.83981664  63.77031531  59.31844506]
> 454.8398
> 63.7703
> 59.3184
> Intercept:  -1073.5124
> MSE:  434529.9361

Those are the values (coefficients, intercept and mean square error). However, when I run it again, I get a different output shown below

> Coeff:  [462.0304152   61.17909189 269.41075305]
> 462.0304
> 61.1791
> 269.4108
> Intercept:  -1462.2449
> MSE:  4014768.0049

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited. Please check and see if you can now understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal to get different coefficients with each training of your linear regression. Indeed, initially the coefficients are set randomly and then are progressively updated with [the least squares method](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_des_moindres_carr%C3%A9s). If you want to have the same coefficients for each training, you can set the seed with :

```
numpy.random.seed(42)
```